# Shopify Liquid Object Rules

Tags: shopify, liquid

From Shopify's demo https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects

```
{% for product in collections.frontpage.products %}
  {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This piece of code shows the object collection outputing title `{{ product.title }}`

Where does the loop collections.`frontpage.products` come from? 
I dont see `frontpage` in the list of objects, is this a reserved special object? If so are there others?
What are the rules concatenating objects together like this?

Shopify's documentation is not clear where and how I can join objects together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to read more about collections and how for loop work.

The following line `collections.frontpage.products` means -> Get me all Products inside the collection that have a handle called `frontpage`.

So you call a specific collection when you target it's handle this way `collections.COLLECTION_HANDLE` or this way `collections[COLLECTION_HANDLE]`.

The frontpage collection is the default collection that comes with Shopify. Another default collections is the `all` collection, that doesn't need to have a collection page.

So if you go to your Shopify admin and look into `Products -> Collections` you should see a collection called `Homepage` that has a handle of `frontpage`. You are targeting that collection.

---

So to answer your question - No `frontpage` is not a special object, it's just a handle of a collection.

You can call a different collection this way as well `collections.all.products` where it will return all products no matter in which collection they are attached to, where `all` is the exception and you can call it like a special handle, since it doesn't require a collection to be created in order to exist. ( 
but at the same time you can overwrite it if you create an `all` collection )